# rename button on yii FileUpload

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I am using Yii file upload and want to rename the button from `Browse` to `something else`. how do i do this?

model

```
<?php 
class Fileupload extends CFormModel
{


    public $jobs;
    // ... other attributes

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(

            array('jobs', 
                    'file', 
                    'types'=>'csv, xls, xlsx'
            ),
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
                'jobs' => 'Uploaded file',
        );
    }
}
```

view

```
echo CHtml::activeFileField(new Fileupload,'jobs', array('onChange'=>'showLoadDialog();submit(this)',"name"=>"Upload"));
```

the html output i get is

```
<input id="ytUpload" type="hidden" name="Upload" value="">
<input id="Upload" type="file" name="Upload" onchange="showLoadDialog();submit(this)">
```

Comment: why am i being downvoted for?

Comment: +1 Don't worry for downvoted. U can't change the `browse`text as it is browser default. But you can do something with soem other plugin like  swfupload. But it is not necessary for small text change.

Comment: I am trying to add twitter boostrap but somewhere it is not working. i have followed this http://cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't control file upload style or label by editing the html

You need something a bit advanced like using javascript uploader.

i suggest this one: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

Comment: Good, But is there any Yii solution?

Comment: mmmm Yes, there's 
- jQuery Uploader www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload